# EF Profiler - How does it work?

Tags: .net, debugging, entity-framework

I'm trying to learn more about trying to tap into the ADO.Net / EF pipeline and how to unintuitively hook into the pipeline (to dump queries, results, etc to my log).

Everything I have seen says that there is no way to unobtrusively or without using SQL Profiler... But I know its possible as the best [EF Profiler](http://efprof.com/) manages to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how exactly EfProf works internally, but EF is extensible in the form of custom providers - using a custom provider you can wrap an existing provider (i.e. SQL Server) and inspect all traffic - this allows profiling. This article focuses on this topic: [Tracing and Caching Provider Wrappers for Entity Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) - there's sample code provided.

> Whenever you issue a LINQ or Entity
>   SQL query through an ObjectContext
>   instance, the query passes through a
>   series of layers (see the picture
>   below). At high level we can say that
>   all queries and updates from
>   ObjectContext are translated and
>   executed through EntityConnection,
>   which in turns talks to
>   server-specific data provider such as
>   SqlClient or Sql Server CE client.
>
> Provider interface used by Entity
>   Framework is stackable, which means
>   it’s possible to write a provider
>   which will wrap another provider and
>   intercept communication between Entity
>   Framework and the original provider.
>
> The wrapper provider gets a chance do
>   interesting things, such as:
>
> **Examining query trees and commands before they are executed**
>
> Controlling connections, commands,
>   transactions, data readers

[image]